# Impact on performance on an Indexed table after deletion Mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, datatables, query-optimization

I have a table with 10bn rows and my search query pulls 1.5mn rows which are indexed. My question is if I delete the unnecessary rows and reduce to 3 Mn rows, i guess my search criteria performance will increase. Here is my Question

1. How does Indexing works if I am query same amount of data with 10bn Rows vs 3 Mn rows

Here is my Table Details and simple search query. The @startdate is an input and it will be always one month

```
CREATE TABLE `ABCD` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VAL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NVAL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOC` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `DESC` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateCreat` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),   
  KEY `IDX_DOC` (`DOC`), -- BTREE NON-UNIQUE
  KEY `INDEX_DESC` (`DESC`), -- BTREE NON-UNIQUE
  KEY `INDEX_DateCreat` (`DateCreat`) -- BTREE NON-UNIQUE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14755842749 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


SELECT  
     MONTH(@START_DATE) 'Month'
     ,count(distinct  DOC) 'Docs'

FROM 
    ABCD USE INDEX (IDX_DOC, INDEX_DateCreat)
WHERE
    DateCreat >= @START_DATE and DateCreat < @END_DATE
```

Comment: Please, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info). Then [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: I have add additional comments to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Too long for a Comment.)

It depends.  In some situations there will be no improvement; in some, there will be a significant improvement.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample `DELETE` and `SELECT`.

How is the 'search' done -- via `PRIMARY KEY`?  Secondary key?  Non-indexed column(s)?

Are the deleted rows at one "end" of the table (eg purging "old" data)?  Or scattered?

What do you do with the 1.5M rows returned?  (That is a lot!)

How does indexing work.  Start by reading about B+Trees in Wikipedia.  Or are you using `FULLTEXT`?  Or `SPATIAL`?

**A speedup**

Don't you want to `GROUP BY MONTH(DateCreat)` and `SELECT MONTH(DateCreat)` ?  Or are you really going to display a range of months but label them by just one month?

Anyway, If you have a summary table -- perhaps by the day -- you could ver efficiently sum the counts in the summary table to very rapidly fetch the `COUNT`.

**Re INDEX**

I still need to know whether you are deleting "old" rows or rows scattered across the 'months'.

If you are deleting "old" rows, then `PARTITIONing` will make that much more efficient.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

If you are deleting rows scattered throughout the table, let's get into BTrees.  The data will be ordered by the PK.  That's `id`, which is probably chronologically ordered (or at least approximately so).

Data is stored in blocks, perhaps 100 rows per block, maybe more if those varchars hold "short" strings.  A block is 16KB.

As you delete *scattered* rows, you will be shrinking the number of rows in some blocks, but not reducing the number of blocks.  (OK, if two adjacent blocks are sparse enough, they will be merged together.)

The speed of a query that is hitting a huge table (too big to be cached in ram) is determined mostly by the number of *block* touched.

So, the `DELETE` won't help the performance of this query much.

**Better index**

*For this one query*, replacing `INDEX(doc)` by `INDEX(doc, date_creat)` *or* replacing `INDEX(date_creat)` by `INDEX(date_creat, doc)` would speed up the query, even before any Delete.  (It is OK to change both indexes.  But that may take a long time.)

Each secondary index is a BTree.  This BTree is subject to changes similar to what I mentioned above during a delete.  That is, deleting some docs is likely to remove blocks from the first index or deleting "old" rows is very likely to delete a big chunk of the second index.  Meanwhile, the other index will mostly become less dense.

Those suggested indexes are "covering".  This means that the query can be performed using *only* the `INDEX`.

**Efficiency of index**

Again I have to say "it depends"...

As a Rule of Thumb, if more than about 20% of an index is to be used, the index will be ignored.  That is, if `WHERE DateCreat >= @START_DATE and DateCreat < @END_DATE` is a *small* range of dates, any index *starting with* `DateCreat` will be considered.  For a large range, the indexes will be ignored and the table will be used.

**Summary of best**

Larger date range:  `INDEX(date_creat, doc)` -- filtering will take place *and* covering.  Without it, the entire table will be scanned; in this case the number of blocks in the table is critical -- so, back to what the Delete did or did not do.

Smaller date range:  `INDEX(date_creat, doc)` is best, but ``INDEX(date_creat)` comes in second.  The Delete has less effect, but now the effect needs to be considered in both BTrees (the data and the index).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28714852)

Comment: This is a large table and planning to purge. I know how the index works, but want to know how the index search works w.r.t number of rows. If the index is helping me to search the criteria and pulling the same amount of data , does the number of rows matters ?

Comment: @Musthafa - Sorry if I overwhelmed you.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield - Did the OP and I add enough to justify reopening?

Comment: @RickJames Thanks Rick this helps me a lot. Regarding delete , this table contains 7 year data and i will be moving to a historical table and keep only a year in the original

Comment: @RickJames: I don't think so, no. The question is basically, "What will happen if I do this?". The answer is "Do that and find out". For performance questions, the answer is always testing and analysis, not guesswork.

Comment: @Musthafa - My partitioning link discusses the partitioning, perhaps by month or year for your case.  And about "transportable tablespaces" if the goal is to move the old data to a separate table.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield - I contend that some advice or imprecise advice is better than none.  Initially, the question was vague and incomplete.  But, between the edited question and added Comments, it is now clear that performance help, archiving help, and understanding of indexes were desired.  I have addressed all of those.